# What kind of data should be kept in connected tables?

Tags: database, entity-framework, data-binding, relational-database

I have one question about manipulating with data in database.
I have tables like this:

[image]

The question is, what kind of data should I keep in `Status` table in it's Name property?
I have two possibilities:

1. Keep there `strings`, for example: 'Normal', 'Hired', 'Banned', 'Moderator' etc.
2. Keep there `ints`, corresponding to `Enum` type in my project, also containing all those 'Normal', 'Hired', etc.

Is there any rule about it? I saw the second option(`enum`) in one project, and the author justified his choice, with the fact, that it's easier for him, to parse those int's to managed code, just with this line:

```
(StatusEnum)statusInt;
```

In my opinion, the first option(`strings`) is more professional, because the database is more independent. But actually I don't know how to argue, because it only brings me a problem: I have to parse those strings to managed `Enum type` with two lines (`Enum.TryParse...`).

Can somebody please, give me their opinion?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336846/database-enums-pros-and-cons. I personally recommend enum, cause you will be protected from typos and it requires less disk space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go with enum you don't need a special table for that. You will simply use Status integer value in `User` table and map it to enum directly in EF designer. Related table makes sense if your `Status` is an entity. Is it something you can change, you can add or delete at runtime? If yes make it a table with string name. If no make it an enum field in `User` table.